# Unable to write to Arduino from Android using BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm having a problem. I am attempting to write a value to my Arduino from my Android smartphone over BLE. My board is a Genuino 101, so I am using CurieBLE. I am able to access the correct service and characteristic, but I always get a false value returned from writeCharacteristic. The onCharacteristicWrite function is also not being called.

Here is the code for my Bluetooth class:

```
public class BluetoothActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private BluetoothAdapter btAdapt = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
private boolean mScan;
private BluetoothGatt mGatt;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private static final long SCAN_TIME = 10000;
private static final String DEVICE_ADDRESS = "98:4F:EE:0F:CB:69";
private static final String LIGHT_SERVICE = "19B10000-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214";
private Context context = this;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic sendVal;

/**
 * Function to scan device
 * @param enable: Switch to begin scanning
 */
public void ScanDevice(final boolean enable){
    if(enable){
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScan = false;
                btAdapt.stopLeScan(mCallback);
            }
        }, SCAN_TIME);

        mScan = true;
        btAdapt.startLeScan(mCallback);
    }else{
        mScan = false;
        btAdapt.stopLeScan(mCallback);
    }
}


/**
 * Callback to execute upon finding device.
 */
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    //!Function to connect to device
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int i, byte[] bytes) {
        String address = device.getAddress();
        if(address.equals(DEVICE_ADDRESS)) {
            mGatt = device.connectGatt(context, false, bCallback);
            Log.i("BTConnect", "Found it!");
        }
        else{
            Log.i("BTConnect", "Wrong device!");
        }
    }
};


/**
 * Callback to find services of device.
 */
private final BluetoothGattCallback bCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

    //!Function to discover services
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        gatt.discoverServices();
    }

    //!Function to deal with discovered services
    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        mGatt = gatt;
        List<BluetoothGattService> bluetoothGattServiceList= mGatt.getServices();
        BluetoothGattService LightUp = bluetoothGattServiceList.get(findService(bluetoothGattServiceList));
        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> bluetoothGattCharacteristicList = LightUp.getCharacteristics();
        sendVal = bluetoothGattCharacteristicList.get(findCharacteristic(bluetoothGattCharacteristicList));
    }

    //!Function to deal with characteristic writes
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
            Log.i("BTWrite","Write to Characteristic Success!");
        }else{
            Log.i("BTWrite","Blast!Foiled!");
        }
    }
};

//!Function to find the right service
private int findService(List<BluetoothGattService> list){
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i).getUuid().equals(LIGHT_SERVICE)){
            index = i;break;}
    }
    return index;
}

//!Function to find the right characteristic
private int findCharacteristic(List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> list){
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i).getUuid().equals(LIGHT_SERVICE)){
            index = i;break;}
    }
    return index;
}

//!Function to actually write to Arduino
public boolean WriteVal(){
    if(sendVal==null){
        Log.i("BTWrite", "Disconnected!");
        return false;
    }
    byte[] value = new byte[1];
    value[0] = (byte) (Math.random() * 126);
    sendVal.setValue(value);
    boolean ans = mGatt.writeCharacteristic(sendVal);
    return ans;
}

}
```

And here is the main class which contains the UI:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapt = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
BluetoothActivity btActivity = new BluetoothActivity();

/**
 * Main function for opening screen.
 * @param savedInstanceState: Instance for creation
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//!Open the layout
    if(btAdapt.isEnabled()){
        Intent enableBt = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBt, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);//!Set listener to button
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            btActivity.ScanDevice(true);break;//!Scan for shisha
        case R.id.button2:
            btActivity.WriteVal();break;//!Write to shisha
    }
}


}
```

I appreciate all your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your infinite do-while loop doesn't look so good (why is it there?). Since having that means you won't return from the onServicesDiscovered method, and therefore you block the onCharacteristicWrite callback from running (it gets enqueued). Also note that in Android you may only have one outstanding GATT operation per BluetoothGatt object (you must wait until the corresponding callback arrives before you can issue another operation). That is the reason for your writeCharacteristic calls return false.

Comment: Even after the do while loop is remove, the onCharacteristicWrite function is not called. I am not performing any read/write GATT operation other than this one. It fails from the very first instance. Characteristic read are successful.